# Bypass writing figures to folder but direct to excel instead

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

Currently I can

1. Generate figures in for loop
2. save them to directory `plt.savefig`
3. append images from directory using `worksheet.insert_image` to existing excel which has `df1, df2`

I would like to skip step 2 and put generated images directly to excel. Is this possible?

Input:

```
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test', engine='xlsxwriter')
            for i in range(.....shape[1]):
                plt.figure()
                fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)
                .
                .
                .
                plt.savefig(f'{plot_l[i]}.jpg')
                plt.close()
    
        
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(name='graphs')   
        .
        .
        .
        for i,image in enumerate(l):
            worksheet.insert_image(....)    
    
        df1.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='test1'...)
        df2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='test2'...)

        workbook.close() 
        writer.save()
```

Output:
`DuplicateWorksheetName: Sheetname 'plots', with case ignored, is already in use.`

Desired Output:
excel with sheets `test1`, `test2` and `plots`

Comment: Remove `plt.savefig(f'{plot_l[i]}.jpg')`  *to skip step 2*.

Comment: @QuangHoang I get the same error. I think the issue is with the mixing of `workbook.close()` and the writer?